Speed up UPDATE query (one table with index)
there. Is it possible to speed up my UPDATE query?
DB mariadb:10.3
-- dev_db_5843.subscription

CREATE TABLE `subscription`
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `work_to_dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_subscription_work_to_dt` (`work_to_dt`) USING BTREE,
)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4187656 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

and i have sql query
UPDATE subscription
SET `status`= 2
WHERE
    subscription.`status` = 1 AND
    subscription.work_to_dt IS NOT NULL AND
    subscription.work_to_dt < '2024-04-01 14:30:31';

Table subscription has 3 629 036 rows. Rows for UPDATE query is 958.
EXPLAIN
UPDATE subscription
SET `status`= 2
WHERE
    subscription.`status` = 1 AND
    subscription.work_to_dt IS NOT NULL AND
    subscription.work_to_dt < '2024-04-01 14:30:31';


UPDATE duration is about 5 seconds

If remove index from work_to_dt column I have the same query duration about ~5 seconds

Why it happens? I thought that column index must speed up my update query, that's wrong i do?

There are two restrictions: status = 1 and work_to_dt < xxx. How restrictive are these conditions. How many rows do you get for status = 1 alone? How many for work_to_dt < xxx alone? For the combination it is 958, but there is no index on the combined columns.

For status=1 (973 rows), for work_to_dt < 2024-04-01 14:30:31 (1 146 585 rows)

Then the restriction on work_to_dt is not selective and the DBMS should not use the index. A simple full table scan should be faster than accessing the rows via this index. The DBMS made a mistake by choosing the index approach. An index on (status) or on (status, work_to_dt) on the other hand would be appropriate, and the DBMS should choose this index if it existed.

The rows updating itself (writing new data to disk) is the longest operation within the query execution. The time which is used for the rows to be updated selection is too small, so you cannot see the difference (3% is the measurement error, I think).

mariadb 10.3 has been unsupported and no longer receiving security updates for almost a year.  consider it insecure and plan to update to one of the long term support versions (10.11 or 10.6) or the current stable version 11.3 as soon as possible

@akina That's not always true. A full table scan can be materially expensive too. For example, the op has now reduced the wall-time to 0.3s (better than 10x faster).

subscription.work_to_dt IS NOT NULL is not necessary as NULL isn't <= to anything.
The best index for your case will be (status, work_to_date) as a single composite index (not two separate indexes).  This will find the rows to update quickest.
Having just (work_to_date) will mean that all the rows with status = 1 will be mixed in with all the other status values too. Those other rows will still need to be scanned and then actively ignored.

Yes, set index(status, work_to_date) - good idea. But query duration is the same

@Lev Kakalashvili: What does EXPLAIN say? Does the DBMS use the new index for the update? As you mentioned in the request comments that status = 1 is extremely restrictive, the DBMS should use this index and thus speed up the update process immensely.

EXPLAIN INDEX

@LevKakalashvili you've made a (work_to_date, status) index, which is going to be just about as useless as just work_to_date.  do make a (status, work_to_date) index and try again.  whenever you do a multi-column index, the columns that you want a range of go last.

@ysth: thanks a lot. I don't know about it. And INDEX(status, work_to_dt) helps me. Now update for about 6600 rows takes only 0,3 seconds

Once you add INDEX(status, work_to_dt), drop INDEX(status) since it will be unnecessary and possibly errorously used.
